# Working remotely for a US employer while in UK with student dependent visa

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, contracts

I am an Indian staying in the UK with a student-dependent visa with a full work permit. A US company wants to hire me to work remotely in the UK as a Software Engineer. They don’t have operations in the UK. Can they acquire me as a permanent employee in this case? What all are the options they have? Should I look for an Umbrella company in UK? Also to which country I should pay the tax?

Comment: You'll probably have to set yourself up as an independent contractor.  You'll pay tax in the UK.  I don't know enough about the details to post an answer.  I do know that the company shouldn't hire you as a local employee in the US if you're not in the US.

Comment: @phoog Thank you